# Keep track of who has checked out repositories

Tags: svn

```
CentOS 5.3
subversion 1.4.2
```

Our company would like to know who has checked out a project.

Currently we have a internal server where are repositories are located.

We are also using websvn to view the repositories.

However, we would like to keep track of who has checked out a repository.

Is there anyway subversion can do this. Or is there a another web interface like websvn that can do this?

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: Does your company have a practical reason for doing this? I'm just curious if this has benefits I don't understand.

Comment: What if people view/export all files without checking them out?  This could bypass your checkout monitoring...

Comment: @JoshD, Our company is changing its policy and now would like to know the who has checked out what projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is a straight forward way to do this.

probably you can find who has run a svn checkout by grepping your http access log. I think svn uses OPTIONS/PROPFIND to do a checkout, similarly it uses MKACTIVITY for checkin and so forth.

- For CentOS the below command should help

  ```
  * grep -h '\"OPTIONS ' /etc/httpd/logs/access_* | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort | uniq
  ```

However this will give you the checkout history from day one. Also there is no way you can find if someone removed the working copy after checkout. The above command can be enriched by changing the apache configuration to store the access logs for a day/hour/week/etc and grep the latest file. This way you can get the results for a day/hour/week and so on.